# Automatically fill in grouped products / Client want "Kits" type of products

Tags: product, grouped-products

I have a client who wants a "kit" type of product. It would ideally look like a grouped product (that's why i want to use it), but the "kits" should be pre filled out in a way.

For example if you are selling a "Playstation 4 Starter Kit" with a Playstation 4 console, Playstation 4 handkontroll and let's NFL 2017 game.

But for example, if you click into this "kit" and you would like to add another controller, you would be able to edit the "1" to a "2". So it would pretty much be a grouped product with pre-filled values.

Any idea how it's possible to do this in Magento 1.9.x?

Comment: Did you try bundle products? There you can have default qtys

Answer (score 0):

yes, you just go into admin> manage catalog> edit your group item and set the quantities you want as defaults and save, the customer can increase or decrease the set values